# Android TelephonyManager subscriberid()

Tags: android, telephonymanager, networkstatsmanager

I'm using android TelephonyManager to get the subcriber Id ( using getSubscriberId() method )

but based on the new android permission update they have mention below statement

> getSubscriberId        Added in API level 1
>
> public String **getSubscriberId ()**
>
> If the calling app's target SDK is API level 28 or lower and the app
> has the READ_PHONE_STATE permission then null is returned.
>
> If the
> calling app's target SDK is API level 28 or lower and the app does not
> have the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, or if the calling app is
> targeting API level 29 or higher, then a SecurityException is thrown

But still I could get the subscriber Id using the **getSubscriberId()** in android api level 24 ( which is running on android emulator). It givess proper value for subscriber Id

Will it be a problem in other real devices ( api level <= 28). because my app will not work without subscriber Id

Comment: try running your app on an emulator running API level 29 (Android 10), it should either return null or throw an exception

Comment: app only target API level 28 or below

Comment: setting `targetSdk` = 28 doesn't mean the app can't be run on API levels 29 or above, it just means the app was built with API level 28. If you want to limit your app to run only on Android Pie and below set `android:maxSdkVersion` just note that it's discouraged to use it because devices can upgrade their Android version, in which case your app will be uninstalled unexpectedly